# Talend: How to copy the file with modified as of today

Tags: talend

I have a job in Talend which will connect to a ftp folder and look for the files eg:ABCD. This file is created everyday and its placed in the ftp path  and i need to move this files to some other folder. I'm new to talend and Java. Could you please help me how to move this file when and only the file last modified date as of the job run date.

Comment: Hi Chaitanya, Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please share your code what you have tried so far and what error you are facing..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tFTPFileProperties` to obtain the properties of the remote file, then in a javarow access those properties. You can then compare to current date either in the `tJavaRow` and stick the results in a global variable or put the date in a global variable.  You then use an IF trigger to join to the `tFTPGet` component.

The IF trigger will either check the results of your compare, or do the compare. It will only execute the FTP Get if true.

This shows overall job structure, including the fields made available from the file properties:

[image]

This shows how to obtain the datetime of the remote file.  This is where you will need to stick it in a global variable (code for that is not shown) so you can use it in your IF trigger code. 
[image]

This shows the datetime of the remote file when the job is run.
[image]

This points you in the right direction but you will need to still do some work.  You will need to do the compare in your IF trigger and know how to compare dates.